# How to create a complete directory structure with a single command?

Tags: command-line, directory

How to create a complete directory structure with a single command?

By this question I mean, if I wanted to create a directory structure like below in one go using a command.

```
/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/
```

then what command shall I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question,below command will do the job you want in just the way you want :) This can be done with mkdir (make directory command) as shown below:

```
root@test:~# sudo mkdir -p /abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/  
root@test:~#
```

If you want it to show you the directories it created while it is working then use verbose with it as shown below:

```
root@test:~# sudo mkdir -pv /abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd'
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx'  
mkdir: created directory `/abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/'  
root@test:~#
```

Enjoy!! :)

Comment: Please do not post a (duplicate) answer, while you are aware of the duplicate. Either post an answer there or edit the question / title to improve the findability.

Answer (score 5):

`mkdir -p /abcd/efgh/ijkl/mnop/qrst/uvwx/yz/`

`mkdir` is "make directory"

The -p option creates the parent directories if they do not already exist.